# Negative index in pandas give a KeyError unlike lists

Tags: pandas, indexing, slice, series, keyerror

With Python lists you can slice with negative indices.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(a[-1])
```

will print `9` as expected.

However,

```
a = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
print(a[-1])
```

gives `KeyError: -1L`

Answer (score 13):

Use [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to get by position rather than label:

```
In [11]: a.iloc[-1]
Out[11]: 9
```

*See [selection section of the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-integer).*